# Linux equivalent for the Windows certificate store

Tags: windows, linux, store, certificate

Is there any fixed or known location for storing certificates in Linux, something like the Windows certificate store?

Thanks.

Comment: Related question https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, for system certificates, use

```
/etc/ssl/certs
```

AND

```
/etc/ssl/private (chmod 700)
```

For user SSH keys use the user's home folder, in a hidden folder named .ssh.

```
/home/user/.ssh
```

OR

```
~/.ssh
```

For webservers like apache, you can override the default location of certificates found in httpd.conf.

Comment: when did SSH folder start to contain certificates, used mainly for SSL and almost never for SSH? Aren't you mixing them with SSH keys?

Comment: You're right Eugene, I read too quickly ;).
I updated to include locsation for certs as well as personal ssh keys.

Comment: What about TLS (ssl) client certificates?