# windows-my certificate store equivalent linux

Tags: java, linux, certificate, pfx

I have a pfx file which I've stored on my windows machine. I'm able to access it in my java program using

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html

However, is there some kind of equivalent way I can install and access the certificate in java on a linux platform?

I also saw this link:
[Linux equivalent for the Windows certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267573/linux-equivalent-for-the-windows-certificate-store)

Are these accessible in a java api?

Comment: Isn't the pfx-file just a pkcs12-container, meaning it should be rather portable between operating systems? Which again means that you can just load the file using the KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12").load(new new FileInputStream("<your-file-name>.pfx"), "testPass".toCharArray());? Could be I'm wrong :-)

Comment: yeah that's true. however, i don't want to store the password of the pfx file in my program b/c of security risks. I want to install it on the linux machine and then access the certificate during runtime

Answer (score 1):

Reading your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267573/linux-equivalent-for-the-windows-certificate-store) and several post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1700/what-is-the-keyring-or-keychain), there is no available system keystore for linux in a similar way to Windows. There is only an historical OpenSSL convention to store in the filesystem certificates `/etc/ssl/certs` and keys `/etc/ssl/private`

Therefore, it is needed to install an extra package to manage keys. I have found

- Mozilla firefox keystore
- [Gnome keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeKeyring?action=show&redirect=GnomeKeyring)

**Mozilla Firefox Keystore**

Java applications launched from browsers (almostd deprecated) applets that needed to access user's keystore, got certificates from Mozilla Firefox's keystore. You can use it also from a Java local application. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/keystores.html

> 1. Create jss directory under Mozilla's installed directory.
> 2. Copy JSS JAR file into the jss directory.
> 3. Copy JSS native library .so into Mozilla's installed directory.
> 4. Set environment variable MOZILLA_HOME to Mozilla's installed directory in Mozilla's launch script.
> 5. Change environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include Mozilla's installed directory in Mozilla's launch script.

In this [blog](http://finger-in-the-eye.blogspot.com.es/2007/03/cmo-acceder-al-keystore-de-firefox-con.html?m=1) is also explained (spanish)

This is a well-known alternative to get a managed keystore on Linux without using the filesystem.

**Gnome keyring**

I have found this project, but I can not make sure it works properly. It has a PKCS#11 interface, so it should be accesible from Java using the suitable driver