# X509Store location for .NetCore on Linux systems

Tags: powershell, .net-core

I've recently discovered the *[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]* class in .NetCore.

So I tried some basic interaction with PowerShell to import PFX certificate files. This really simplifies working with certificates in cross-platform scenarios :D

```
$cert = Get-PFXCertificate -FilePath '~/myCert.pfx'
$Store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new('My')
$Store.Open('ReadWrite')
$Store.Add($cert)
$Store.Certificates
$Store.Close()
```

Where can I find this store on a Linux system? Is there a specific file per store (MY, Root)?

### Solution

.NetCore / corefx related user certificate store is located in:

```
~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/*
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Local Machine and Current User Certificate Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores)

> Each of the system certificate stores has the following types:
>
> - **Local machine certificate store**: This type of certificate store is local to the computer and is global to all users on the computer. This
>     certificate store is located in the registry under the
>     `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root.
> - **Current user certificate store**: This type of certificate store is local to a user account on the computer. This certificate store is
>     located in the registry under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` root.

You could check e.g. the following `Registry` provider locations (nothing legible inside):

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root
HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My
HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root
```

And where are the registry files stored? Read e.g. [Registry Hives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/registry-hives) Microsoft article (again, nothing legible inside)…

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know where I can find details about the location on Linux systems?

Comment: @OCram85 Answers to [SSL Certificate Location on UNIX/Linux](https://serverfault.com/q/62496/257436) and [Linux equivalent for the Windows certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4267573/3439404) could help. Sorry, my Linux experience  starts and ends  at [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)…

Comment: Thanks. I really wonder where the X509Store lives in such linux systems. I really didn't found any files related to this like in the openssl paths or /etc/pki/*.