# Valid CA certificates

Tags: node.js, openssl

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326) and app works, but certificates I created with my server key works

I understand that I need to pass ca option with certificates my server accepts, but I don't know how to specify what I need.

**I would like to accept certificates from other CA, not only the ones signed with my server key.**

```
 [The peer's certificate must be chainable to a CA trusted by the server for the connection to be authenticated. When using certificates that are not chainable to a well-known CA, the certificate's CA must be explicitly specified as a trusted or the connection will fail to authenticate.][1] 



   const opts = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('server_key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('server_cert.pem'),
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server_cert.pem') ],
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're validating, but at the very least you would need to have a .CER copy of the other CA certs installed in your machines certificate store in the trusted root certification authorities folder. After that it'd all fall down to validation. Some validation methods automatically query your machines cert store for the certificate. Or you can programmatic it to pull the CA from your certificate store and construct the chain yourself.

The .CER version of the certificate refers to the public copy that does not contain the private keys used for signing a certificate. This cert can validate other certificates that were issued by it, but it cannot sign a certificate.

If you're on a windows machine, you can access your certificate store through the Microsoft Management Console. Open a cmd prompt and type MMC. 
Go to file > Add or Remove Snap In > Certificates and select Add. This will prompt you for the specific certificate store you want. If you click the drop down, you'll see additional folders. This will show all trusted certificate authorities in the given store. You will need to add copies of the other CA signing certs here.

Comment: Sure, will update my answer with more details. What type of machine are you on? Mac, Linux, Windows?

Comment: Linux, ubuntu 19

Comment: Roger, not sure how to do it on linux but I'll dig up some docs. in the meantime I updated my answer to give some more details on .cer files and how the validation process works. You're able to chain validate because you have the entire chain, Leaf cert and the CA. If you want to validate certificates from other CAs you'll need the public copy of their CA stored somewhere. Will be back with more info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267573/linux-equivalent-for-the-windows-certificate-store
How to access a certificate store in Linux

Comment: yes, thank you. My app is like https://prod.idrix.eu/secure/, it opens a window so user can choose browser certificates. I created some certs and it works, but I need it to recon other CAs, not only the ones signed with my server key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200408/discussion-between-eddie-d-and-tramada).